# Erlang - Regex nomatch when it actually matches

Tags: regex, erlang

I am running into some problems with extracting values from a url.

Here is my tested regex code: https://regex101.com/r/rfRmhh/1

In that code are backslashes, and I acted in accord to Erlang's note here by backslashing it again:

> The Erlang literal syntax for strings uses the "\" (backslash)
>   character as an escape code. You need to escape backslashes in literal
>   strings, both in your code and in the shell, with an extra backslash,
>   that is, "\". - http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html

This is my code:

```
get_from_url()->
  Pattern = "/(.+)-([0-9_]+)x([0-9_]+)(-[0-9a-zA-Z(),\\-._]+)*\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF)$/",
  Url = "http://localhost:8001/78326459041381-200x100.jpg",
  re:run(Url, Pattern).
```

It returns simply "nomatch". (But the regex works on the test site.) Secondly, even when I get a match it would return something like `{match,[{0,14},{0,13}]}`. I assume these are the offsets of the matched variable in the list?

Would one then use the `sublist(List1, Start, Len)` function to get the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the leading or trailing `/` in the regex pattern. They are treated as a literal `/` in Erlang (unlike PHP and probably more languages) which is why your match failed.

```
1> Pattern = "(.+)-([0-9_]+)x([0-9_]+)(-[0-9a-zA-Z(),\\-._]+)*\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|JPG|JPEG|PNG|GIF)$".
2> Url = "http://localhost:8001/78326459041381-200x100.jpg".
3> re:run(Url, Pattern).
{match,[{0,48},{0,36},{37,3},{41,3},{-1,0},{45,3}]}
```

This will return a `{match, List}` where `List` is a list of tuples containing the start offset and the length of the match. To get the captured values as a string or binary, you can use the `capture` option:

```
4> re:run(Url, Pattern, [{capture, all, list}]).
{match,["http://localhost:8001/78326459041381-200x100.jpg",
        "http://localhost:8001/78326459041381","200","100",[],
        "jpg"]}
5> re:run(Url, Pattern, [{capture, all, binary}]).
{match,[<<"http://localhost:8001/78326459041381-200x100.jpg">>,
        <<"http://localhost:8001/78326459041381">>,<<"200">>,
        <<"100">>,<<>>,<<"jpg">>]}
```

Comment: Thank you Dogbert. Do you know what to do with my second question? (How do I now get the values, or what exactly is the second list from {match, [...]}?)

Comment: Oops, missed that part. I've added how to do that to my answer.